# Why my ajax doesn't work with link_to but button_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I want to use link_to just like below but it doesn't work. It doesn't do any thing:(

```
<% unless user == current_user %>
  <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
    <%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> ') + 'Un-Follow', user_follow_path(user.to_param, current_user.get_follow(user).id), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => 'btn' %>             
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> ') + 'Follow', user_follows_path(user.to_param), :remote => true, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>             
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But if I code it with button_to just like below, it works perfectly. Why???

```
<% unless user == current_user %>
  <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
    <%= button_to("Un-Follow #{user.username}", user_follow_path(user.to_param, current_user.get_follow(user).id), :method => :delete, :remote => true) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= button_to("Follow #{user.username}", user_follows_path(user.to_param), :remote => true) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: write like this : <%= link_to("Un-Follow #{user.username}", user_follow_path(user.to_param, current_user.get_follow(user).id), :method => :delete, :remote => true) %>

Comment: @VenkatK what about <i class=> part? is it gone??? I'd like to use that to use bootstrap's icon:(

Comment: Check the answer below once

Comment: Do you have rails.js under your javascripts folder? unless download one and include it.

Comment: @HUSTEN hmmm that's weird then, maybe try remove the `remote` attribute? cause i can use it without that attribute.

Comment: @Still.Wang No. In controller I coded  format.js {render :action=>"create.js"} so it only works for ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% unless user == current_user %>
<% if current_user.following?(user) %>
<%= button_to("Un-Follow #{user.username}", user_follow_path(user.to_param, current_user.get_follow(user).id), :method => :delete, :remote => true, 
:class => 'btn btn-primary') %>
<% else %>
<%= button_to("Follow #{user.username}", user_follows_path(user.to_param), 
:remote => true, :class => 'btn btn-primary') %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

i search for link_to atm :)

[edited]

ok i did it :) i need to move some follows action into user controller and use specific route for both link_to. I remove the rubycas layout and use simple devise for auth, the seed is inside the project.

https://github.com/senayar/follower

Comment: Thanks for help! But what about adding icon by <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> ?? Where is that? You probably can't add?

Comment: Will you do me a little favor? could please implement the same thing to index view also when its showing users in list.

Comment: yes it's done here. you need to make the div dynamic because each user need a specific div to remplace by js. https://github.com/senayar/follower

Comment: Thanks sir!!! Why did you need to code whole part in index.html.erb? I used partial and changed '@user' to user in _partial.html.erb and it worked fine

Comment: well i did it like this because it's more easy to debug inside the main view than a partial :) but yes use the partial.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= link_to(user_follow_path(user.to_param, current_user.get_follow(user).id), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :class => 'btn') do %>
   <i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i>
   'Un-Follow'
 <% end %>
```

Try above, that will work with your bootstrap icon

Comment: Thanks for reply:) I tried that. But it still won't work:( It does nothing. Did you try on your own and worked???

Comment: I already used that type of link tag. But not for `:remote=>true`